# How to Rotate an Image and then Save New Rotated Image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, image-manipulation

I am trying to add functionality to rotate an image on button click and then when the submit button is clicked the image would be saved rotated. So it can't just visually be rotated using CSS, but the image file itself rotated and then saved on top of the original image file.

I was looking into doing this with PHP using [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) but still not 100% sure on the correct way to rotate the image when a button is clicked. And then save that rotated button on submit.

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
?>
```

Just not sure how to take the above code and make it work when a button is clicked. And then saved when a submit button is clicked. If there is an easier solution using javascript/jquery I am also fine with using that if it is an easier/better implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery rotate an image and save them with same name file (overwrite)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336833/jquery-rotate-an-image-and-save-them-with-same-name-file-overwrite)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the original image file that's on the server, you just have to add parameters to the final imagejpeg() call to indicate where you want to save the result:

```
imagejpeg($rotate, $filename);
```

Just be wary that JPEG is a lossy format, so ANY resaving at all (even if you don't rotate it) will result in an impact to the image quality. You can specify the image quality as a 3rd parameter to that same call (if you want to try to preserve as much quality as possible at the expense of increased file size):

```
imagejpeg($rotate, $filename, 90); // Saves at 90 quality
```

Now, if this is dealing with a client-side image, it's a different story. PHP runs on the server, so it's only going to be able to work with images that are also on or accessible by that same server. The PHP on the server cannot rotate and overwrite an image that sits on the visitor's machine.

In order for that to happen, the image would have to be uploaded from the visitor to the server, then rotated, and then the visitor would need to manually save the image back to their own machine. PHP cannot touch the file systems of visitors' machines, and cannot FORCE visitor browsers to download and overwrite an existing file.

So if this is all on the server side of things, then the PHP approach you have will definitely work.